# How can I make the active navbar link change background color? Bootstrap 4.

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I realize this question has been asked several times, but none of the solutions have worked for me. Here is my HTML:

```
<div  class="navbar-light" style="position: sticky; top: 0px; background: #fff0d8; z-index:99;">  <!--z-index to stay on top of everything else-->
<div class="container">
<ul class="sc-nav nav navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 flex-md-row">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">oihdma</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">saaaassas</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">fffffffffffff</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">dsdsd</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">fsfsfsfs</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">fffff</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">xxxxx</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = this.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    $('a[href="' + filename + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

I left this script in the page footer so it is executed after page load.

Finally, my CSS:

```
  ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:focus, ul.nav a:active { background-color: #FDCBA3;}
```

Hover and focus work as intended, but NOT active. The script makes the link active, the color of the text changes and that works fine. But the background color won't change. It changes on hovering and on focus, but not when clicked.

Comment: if your jquery adds the active class, shouldn't your css also include it?

Comment: TO CLARIFY: When a link is not defined i.e. <a href="#">, then when clicked, the background color remains changed until I click on some other part of the page. But when I click on a defined link in the navbar, the color reverts on page load.

Comment: I tested this on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us3L90fs/) and it should work. It did work on JsFiddle without any changes

Comment: It works until you click on some other part of the page, and unless the link is actually defined. A page load stops the link background being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the active element in Firefox and realized that I was changing the wrong CSS. This is what worked:

```
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:focus, .active { background-color: #FDCBA3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `:active` pseudo-class is different than the `.active` class you're setting in your Javascript.

Try the following:

```
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:focus, ul.nav a.active { background-color: #FDCBA3;}
```

Comment: Hmm... no change unfortunately.